# VSCode menu bar and title bar is bigger than usual

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode Insiders and have recently been getting this problem where the menu bar and the title bar is bigger than usual. How can i fix this??

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Comment: Looks nothing wrong with your screen shot

Comment: The size of the menu bar takes up the entire sidebar.

Comment: Not in the image you posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a probably a known issue. They have changed the "zoom-out" behavior of the title bar in the latest version: while it scales-up when you zoom in the interface, it stays to the "native" height when you zoom-out.

Unfortunately I could not find an option to disable this behavior and allow titlebar scaling when you zoom-out.

You can offer feedback to the team in the thread here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/151803

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the shortcut to decrease the size of the whole editor using:

> Decrease the Size of the whole editor -> Ctrl + Minus(-)

> Increase the Size of the whole editor -> Ctrl + Plus(+)
> Blockquote

[Attached Demo of working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epxbQ.gif)

If the above solution doesn't work, check out the discussion [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/54796)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. The discussion referred seems like a different issue as the size of my menu bar doesn't change no matter the zoom level.